# How to convert the below Tensorflow code to Pytorch (transfer learning)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to know how to convert the below codes(Tensorflow) to Pytorch.
I've wanted to use DataLoader but I couldn't. Is it possible to use DataLoader for converting? or Can you tell me any other ways to convert?

Thanks a lot :)

---

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image as image_utils
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

def load_and_process_image(image_path):
# Print image's original shape, for reference
print('Original image shape: ', mpimg.imread(image_path).shape)

    # Load in the image with a target size of 224, 224
    image = image_utils.load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    # Convert the image from a PIL format to a numpy array
    image = image_utils.img_to_array(image)
    # Add a dimension for number of images, in our case 1
    image = image.reshape(1,224,224,3)
    # Preprocess image to align with original ImageNet dataset
    image = preprocess_input(image)
    # Print image's shape after processing
    print('Processed image shape: ', image.shape)
    return image
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from torchvision import transforms

class MyData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_path):
        #path of the folder where your images are located
        self.data_path = data_path
        #transforms to perform on image. In general, these are the default normalization used. you can change std, mean values about three channels according to your requirement
        #when ToTensor() is used it automatically permutes the dimensions according to the torch layers
        self.transforms = transforms.Compose([
                              transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
                              transforms.ToTensor(),
                              transforms.Normalize((mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                                    std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

        self.image_path_list = sorted(os.listdir(self.data_path))

    def __len__(self):
        #returns the length of your dataset
        return len(self.image_path_list)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        #pytorch accepts PIL images, use PIL.Image to load images
        image = Image.open(self.image_path_list[idx])
        image = self.transform(image)
        return image
```

Above is a small snippet based on my assumptions from your post. I assumed you would need to resize, permute and normalize about the given mean values. DataLoader is iterate-able. It yields single image at a time.

For example,

```
#instantiate your loader, with the desired parameters. checkout the pytorch documentation for other arguments 
myloader = DataLoader(MyData, batch_size = 32, num_workers = 10)
myloader = iter(myloader)

for i in range(0, 10):
#this yields first 10 batches of your dataset 
img = next(myloader)
```

Hopefully, this is what you are looking for. Please feel free to comment your quires for any further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually it's my first time to use DataLoader. It's hard to use... Are there any good websites to learn about it? and Is it possible to use OpenCV to convert the codes? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you can learn everything from the official documentation itself. What do you mean convert the codes using OpenCV?